# Web Services SOAP to JSON

Tags: android, json, web-services, soap

Until now, I am able to consume some WS using SOAP in my Android application (with kSOAP2 library), but as I read JSON is more lightweight than XML and Android offer native support for JSON Web Services, I am wondering if is it possible consume the same WS using JSON?

Or it should be made some changes on the server side?

Comment: You might consider using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server side will need to produce a JSON output -- something that many REST services will do. So yes, the server side will need to change. SOAP is XML - there is no way around that.